# Data structure with two way O(1) lookup. Hashtable?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable, lookup

I'm implementing a system where I have a list of names and each person has 1 phone number. I need to be able to take a name and look up the phone number, or take a phone number and look up a name.

I know I could do this by having two hashtables - one which goes from names to phone numbers and one which goes from phone numbers to names. Then I can look up in either direction in O(1) time. However this seems like I am storing too much data - every name and every phone number is stored twice.

Is there any way to do this more efficiently? What data structure should I use to store the names and phone numbers?

I am coding in Java if that is relevant.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java does not provide a two-way hash table out-of-the-box. Your solution that relies on two hash tables is as good as it gets, unless you are willing to go with third-party libraries (which would hide the two hash tables for you) or re-implement a significant portion of `HashMap<K,V>`.

> Then I can look up in either direction in O(1) time. However this seems like I am storing too much data - every name and every phone number is stored twice.

Not necessarily: you can use the same object that represents the phone number, in which case there would be a single object for the phone number, with two references to it stored from two hash tables.

Comment: +1 For addressing the "storage" aspect - it's all just references.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using Guava's [`HashBiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html), which is basically two `HashMap`s linked together behind the scenes. See also the [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) interface and its [related article](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap).

Comment: Remember, hash table provides **O(1) amortized**. It's not clear whether requirement is O(1) worst case or amortized. Normally, it would be worst case, unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remember that the object itself is stored only once, and not in both maps. You only need double number of references - so it might not be that bad.
2. You can use Gauva [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) that offers that functionality (and its interface [HashBiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html))