# Best data structure for two way mapping

Tags: java, data-structures

I want a data structure that maps from key to object and vice-versa(unlike HashMaps that map only in a single direction.) An idea could be to store the HashMap within itself for reverse look-up, but it will be an inefficient approach.

What would be the best implementation for two-way mapping?

Comment: Take a look at [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314905/data-structure-with-two-way-o1-lookup-hashtable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simplest idea: wrapper class which contains 2 maps, second with swapped keys/values. You will keep O(1) complexity and will use only slightly more memory since you will (probably) keep there `reference` to object.

Comment: I mentioned this idea in question itself, but I guess there might be better implementations in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Why do you think it will be inefficient? You will keep `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: @TanaySoni Start simple and only look for inefficiencies when you really need to. Do you have any metrics that would signal this approach as a potential bottleneck in your system?

Comment: I'm trying to use mapping for pixels in a image processing applications. Considering the large data set( a typical image has millions of pixels), I am looking for a rather efficient approach.

Comment: @ProblemFactory: Is BitMap implemented the same way?

Comment: I believe you meant BiMap, then "probably" yes, you can download source and check it by yourself.